# Retain value of text box whose radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different radio button, each with a text box value associated to it on my form. A user can select only one radio button at a time and submit the form. However, occasionally a user will enter data in a textbox for one radio button and then choose a different option and enter textbox data in it. Currently it preserves data in both textboxes and submits them as well.

Is there any way I can clear the data and preserve only for the one that got clicked last? Like an onclick event which clears all the data of any other radio button other then the checked one.

just a quick static example code:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="whereEntry" method='post' action=''>
    <input type="radio" name="formOption" id="radio1210" value="1210" checked="checked">Waiting on Approval<br>
    Comment:<input type="text" name="Comment"><br>

    <input type="radio" name="formOption" id="radio1211" value="1211" checked="checked">Waiting on Authorization<br>
     Comment:<input type="text" name="Comment">

     <input type="Submit" value="Submit">Submit
 </form>
```

Textbox value are displayed when radio button is clicked. So If I click a radio button and I enter a value in the comment textbox and then if click another radio button, both the comment box values are retained.

Comment: Show us what u tried so far.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Lets see the HTML for the form

Comment: its all driven dynamically with database values and css, I will try to post a static one just as an example

Comment: As long as you put appropriate classes on the DIVs, jQuery shouldn't care how the HTML was generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

**Html MarkUp**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="gender"/>Male
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<br />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="gender"/>FeMale
<input type="text" id="txt2">
```

**Jquery**

```
$("input:radio").click(function(){
    $("input:text").not($(this).next()).val("");
})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WWgra/1/)